# Construct hierarchy tree from flat list with child field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, hierarchy

I have a list of "page" objects with a child field. This child field references another object in the list. I would like to create a tree hierarchy from this list based on this field.
I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367819/4247296) but it works only if I have a parent field.Here is what my original list looks like:

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  title: 'home',
  child: null
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  title: 'about',
  child: null
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  title: 'team',
  child: 4
  },
  {
  id: 4,
  title: 'company',
  child: 2
  }
]
```

I would like to convert it into a tree structure like this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  title: 'home',
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   title: 'team',
   children:  [
   {
    id: 4,
    title: 'company',
    children: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'about',
    }
  }
]
]
```

I was hoping for a reusable function that I can call against an arbitrary list any time. Anyone know of a good way to handle this? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by using Underscore.js to add parents and then use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367711/construct-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-list-with-parent-field/22367819#22367819)

```
_.each(flat, function (o) {
  o.child.forEach(function (childId) {
    _.findWhere(flat, {id: childId}).parent = o.id;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below builds a tree from a list of objects.
It’s not tight to any format.
The only difference with your example is that you provide the `parent` key, not the `child`.

```
function buildTree(flatList, idFieldName, parentKeyFieldName, fieldNameForChildren) {
    var rootElements = [];
    var lookup = {};

    flatList.forEach(function (flatItem) {
      var itemId = flatItem[idFieldName];
      lookup[itemId] = flatItem;
      flatItem[fieldNameForChildren] = [];
    });

    flatList.forEach(function (flatItem) {
      var parentKey = flatItem[parentKeyFieldName];
      if (parentKey != null) {
        var parentObject = lookup[flatItem[parentKeyFieldName]];
        if(parentObject){
          parentObject[fieldNameForChildren].push(flatItem);
        }else{
          rootElements.push(flatItem);
        }
      } else {
        rootElements.push(flatItem);
      }

    });

    return rootElements;
  }
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfq9yw24/) using your example as input.

The original source [comes from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367711/construct-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-list-with-parent-field/22367819#22367819).