# Construct hierarchy tree from flat list with children field and preserve the children order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, hierarchy

Similar question was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267178/construct-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-list-with-child-field) and [here](http://Construct%20hierarchy%20tree%20from%20flat%20list%20with%20parent%20field?), there are [npm-packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=array%20to%20tree) as well **BUT** - I am not able to find a JavaScript code snippet or npm package which would allow preserving the the **order of the children**

Consider following data structure:

```
var nodes = [{id: 'a', parent: null, children: ['c', 'b']},
             {id: 'b', parent: 'a', children: []},
             {id: 'c', parent: 'a', children: []}]
```

I would like to get a nested object like this:

```
var tree = {id: 'a', parent: null, children: [
    {id: 'c', parent: 'a', children: []},
    {id: 'b', parent: 'a', children: []}
]}
```

The important fact is, that since the order of the children of **a** is **c, b**, the resulting **children** array in the nested structure will preserve the order.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple if you build up a Map first:

```
 const nodeById = new Map(nodes.map(el => [el.id, el]));
```

Then you can easily build up the tree:

```
 let root;

 for(const node of nodes) {
   node.children = node.children.map(id => nodeById.get(id));
   if(!node.parent) root = node;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I had to notice, that this approach mutates the original structure. This is very unfortunate if you work on e.g. a property of a React state object. Is there a possibility to modify your code without the necessity of deep-cloning the original structure or adding additional computational complexity ?

Comment: @karlitos you would ha e to clone before `nodes = nodes.map(n => {...n})`, bit as you mentioned React: Only one version should actually go into the state, changing the states structure is bad

Comment: I did not want to change the Reacts state like this. My goal was to compute derived value based on the state. I will deep-copy the original nodes array to prevent mutating the state. Still, I wonder if there is an more efficient way altogether.

Comment: @karlitos not really, this is still O(n)