# Construct flat array from tree of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree, hierarchy

Suppose I have a tree of objects like the following, perhaps created using the excellent algorithm found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367819/3123195

```
{
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "home",
        "parent": null,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "about",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [{
            "id": 3,
            "title": "team",
            "parent": 2,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "company",
            "parent": 2,
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

(Specifically in this example, the array returned by that function is nested as the `children` array property inside an otherwise empty object.)

How would I convert it back to a flat array?

Comment: I found plenty of questions asking how to create a tree from an array, but none converting back in the other direction, so I've posted the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hope your are familiar with es6:

```
let flatten = (children, extractChildren) => Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  children, 
  children.map(x => flatten(extractChildren(x) || [], extractChildren))
);

let extractChildren = x => x.children;

let flat = flatten(extractChildren(treeStructure), extractChildren)
               .map(x => delete x.children && x);
```

**UPD:**

Sorry, haven't noticed that you need to set parent and level. Please find the new  function below:

```
let flatten = (children, getChildren, level, parent) => Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  children.map(x => ({ ...x, level: level || 1, parent: parent || null })), 
  children.map(x => flatten(getChildren(x) || [], getChildren, (level || 1) + 1, x.id))
);
```

https://jsbin.com/socono/edit?js,console

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how little code that was, and it works perfectly. ES6 is great! Oh, and the level indicator wasn't necessary, I just added it to my implementation for illustration purposes.

Comment: Yeah, es6 and next are inspiring! Glad to read this!
In addition, so far the first solution will be valid es5 if we replace lambdas with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 5):

Since this has been brought up again by a new answer, it's worth looking at a modern simple approach:

```js
const flatten = ({children}) =>
  children .flatMap (({children = [], ...rest}) => [rest, ...flatten ({children})])

let tree = {children: [{id: 1, title: "home", parent: null, children: []}, {id: 2, title: "about", parent: null, children: [{id: 3, title: "team", parent: 2, children: []}, {id: 4, title: "company", parent: 2, children: []}]}]}

console .log (flatten (tree))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Using [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), we map the items in a flat array, recurring on their `children` property.

Answer (score 4):

This function will do the job, plus it adds a level indicator to each object. Immediate children of treeObj will be level 1, their children will be level 2, etc. The `parent` properties are updated as well.

```
function flatten(treeObj, idAttr, parentAttr, childrenAttr, levelAttr) {
    if (!idAttr) idAttr = 'id';
    if (!parentAttr) parentAttr = 'parent';
    if (!childrenAttr) childrenAttr = 'children';
    if (!levelAttr) levelAttr = 'level';

    function flattenChild(childObj, parentId, level) {
        var array = []; 

        var childCopy = angular.extend({}, childObj);
        childCopy[levelAttr] = level;
        childCopy[parentAttr] = parentId;
        delete childCopy[childrenAttr];
        array.push(childCopy);

        array = array.concat(processChildren(childObj, level));

        return array;
    };

    function processChildren(obj, level) {
        if (!level) level = 0;
        var array = [];

        obj[childrenAttr].forEach(function(childObj) {
            array = array.concat(flattenChild(childObj, obj[idAttr], level+1));
        });

        return array;
    };

    var result = processChildren(treeObj);
    return result;
};
```

This solution takes advantage of Angular's `angular.extend()` function to perform a copy of the child object. Wiring this up with any other library's equivalent method or a native function should be a trivial change.

The output given for the above example would be:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "home",
    "parent": null,
    "level": 1
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "about",
    "parent": null,
    "level": 1
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "team",
    "parent": 2,
    "level": 2
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "company",
    "parent": 2,
    "level": 2
}]
```

It is also worth noting that this function does not guarantee the array will be ordered by `id`; it will be based on the order in which the individual objects were encountered during the operation.

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/e4ght06z/)

Comment: You should call your function `flattenChildrenOf` or something similar since it's disregarding the root at all times. Nothing says the root couldn't be an important node.

Comment: Keep in mind that the above answer is recursive, and hence could be improved. Since I could not find a npm module which implements a O(n) solution, I created the following one (unit tested, 100% code coverage, only 0.5 kb in size and includes typings. Maybe it helps someone: npmjs.com/package/performant-array-to-tree

Answer (score 3):

Try following this only assumes each item is having children property

```
class TreeStructureHelper {
   public toArray(nodes: any[], arr: any[]) {
    if (!nodes) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!arr) {
      arr = [];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      arr.push(nodes[i]);
      this.toArray(nodes[i].children, arr);
    }
  return arr;
 }
}
```

Usage

```
 let treeNode =
 {
   children: [{
    id: 1,
    title: "home",
    parent: null,
    children: []
   }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "about",
    parent: null,
    children: [{
        id: 3,
        title: "team",
        parent: 2,
        children: []
     }, {
        id: 4,
        title: "company",
        parent: 2,
        children: []
     }]
   }]
 };
 let flattenArray = _treeStructureHelper.toArray([treeNode], []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes my contribution:

```
function flatNestedList(nestedList, childrenName, parentPropertyName, idName, newFlatList, parentId) {

        if (newFlatList.length === 0)
            newFlatList = [];

        $.each(nestedList, function (i, item) {
            item[parentPropertyName] = parentId;
            newFlatList.push(item);
            if (item[childrenName] && item[childrenName].length > 0) {
                //each level
                flatNestedList(item[childrenName], childrenName, parentPropertyName, idName, newFlatList, item[idName]);
            }
        });

        for (var i in newFlatList)
            delete (newFlatList[i][childrenName]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is data:

```
 const data = {
      id: '1',
      children: [
        {
          id: '2',
          children: [
            {
              id: '4',
              children: [
                {
                  id: '5'
                },
                {
                  id: '6'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              id: '7'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          children: [
            {
              id: '8'
            },
            {
              id: '9'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

In React.JS just declare an array field in state and push items to that array.

```
  const getAllItemsPerChildren = item => {
    array.push(item);
    if (item.children) {
      return item.children.map(i => getAllItemsPerChildren(i));
    }
  }
```

After function call your array in state will hold all items as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more

```js
function flatten(root, parent=null, depth=0, key='id', flat=[], pick=() => {}) {
    flat.push({
        parent,
        [key]: root[key],
        depth: depth++,
        ...pick(root, parent, depth, key, flat)
    });
    
    if(Array.isArray(root.children)) {
        root.children.forEach(child => flatten(child, root[key], depth, key, flat, pick));
    }
}

let sample = {
    "id": 0,
    "children": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "home",
        "parent": null,
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "about",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [{
            "id": 3,
            "title": "team",
            "parent": 2,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "company",
            "parent": 2,
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
};

let flat = [];

flatten(sample, null, 0, 'id', flat, root => ({ title: root.title }));

let expected = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "parent": null,
        "depth": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "depth": 1,
        "title": "home"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 0,
        "depth": 1,
        "title": "about"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent": 2,
        "depth": 2,
        "title": "team"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent": 2,
        "depth": 2,
        "title": "company"
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a recursive function like this:

```
toFlat(items) {
  if(!items || !items.length) {
     return []
  }
  return items.reduce((totalItems, item) => {
    totalItems.push(item)
    return totalItems.concat(toFlat(item.children))
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  Note that [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) can simplify this further, replacing the need for the `reduce(push, concat)` dance.  I added an answer that does this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since this was recently revived, here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Using a well documented and flexible library should make it easier to adjust the functionality if needed

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@19.0.5/lib/index.min.js';

const obj = { children: [{ id: 1, title: 'home', parent: null, children: [] }, { id: 2, title: 'about', parent: null, children: [{ id: 3, title: 'team', parent: 2, children: [] }, { id: 4, title: 'company', parent: 2, children: [] }] }] };

const r = objectScan(['**{children[*]}'], {
  rtn: 'value',
  afterFn: ({ result }) => result.map(({ children, ...rest }) => rest)
})(obj);

console.log(r);
/* => [
  { id: 4, title: 'company', parent: 2 },
  { id: 3, title: 'team', parent: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: 'about', parent: null },
  { id: 1, title: 'home', parent: null }
] */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Disclaimer: I'm the author of object-scan