# Make tree from array And change representation of parent field to object instead of ID

Tags: javascript

I stacked with trivial question but can't find the solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

I have an array of obects

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'home',
        parent: null,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'about',
        parent: null,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'team',
        parent: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'company',
        parent: 2,
    },
    ,
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'department',
        parent: 4,
    },
];
```

To make Tree I use this function:
Solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367711/construct-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-list-with-parent-field)

```
const treeify = (arr) => {
    const tree = [];
    const lookup = {};
    arr.forEach((o) => {
        lookup[o.id] = o;
        lookup[o.id].children = [];
    });
    arr.forEach((o) => {
        if (o.parent !== null) {
            lookup[o.parent].children.push(o);
        } else {
            tree.push(o);
        }
    });
    return tree;
};
```

And finally I have the tree like so:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "home",
    "parent": null,
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "about",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "team",
        "parent": 2,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "company",
        "parent": 2,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "department",
            "parent": 4,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The question is: How replace parent ID with object itself?

I want the result like:

```
            "id": 4,
            "title": "company",
            "parent":  { // <-- how to change just id to object here
                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "about",
                        "parent": null,
                       },
            "children": []
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop approach with a reference for each found node.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, title: 'home', parent: null, }, { id: 2, title: 'about', parent: null }, { id: 3, title: 'team', parent: 2 }, { id: 4, title: 'company', parent: 2 }, { id: 5, title: 'department', parent: 4 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.parent] = t[o.parent] || {};
            t[o.parent].children = t[o.parent].children || [];
            t[o.parent].children.push(t[o.id]);
            if (t[o.id].parent !== null) t[o.id].parent = t[t[o.id].parent];
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for so quick answer! Im sorry, but parents still represents by id only. What I missed?

Comment: do you like to add the parent's node at `parent`? please see edit.

Comment: I need instead "parent": 3 have whole object whit id = 3 i.e. parent: {id: 3, title: 'some title', children: []}. Kind of. Thank you for help!

Comment: it is. don't be fooled by the systems reference id.

Comment: So do you think I shell use recursion then?

Comment: do you get the wanted result with the above code? the code does not use recursions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224133/discussion-between-vladimir-vs-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` method to create recursive function and pass `parentId` and `parent` object to the nested recursive calls. And if there is parent object you assign it to current element.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"title":"home","parent":null},{"id":2,"title":"about","parent":null},{"id":3,"title":"team","parent":2},{"id":4,"title":"company","parent":2},{"id":5,"title":"department","parent":4}]

const treeify = (data, pid = null, parent = null) => {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.parent === pid) {
      const o = { ...e }
      if (parent) o.parent = parent;

      const children = treeify(data, e.id, e);
      if (children.length) o.children = children;

      r.push(o)
    }

    return r;
  }, [])
}

const result = treeify(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My data to work with suppose to be huge, so I'm trying to avoid recursion.